# How to draw class diagram to show inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, class-diagram, visual-paradigm

I want to have a visual class diagram of my classes to show their relationships using Visual Paradigm.
Some of my classes are inherited and also using an instance of other classes.
I just know how to draw classes in class diagram and don't know to show their relationships.

Answer (score 0):

use ***Italics*** named classes for interface 
E.g
-----------------
*Duck*
-----------------

method1
method2

-----------------